# How to comprehensively grasp the status of OU usage in Google Workspace

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

Currently, the configuration of OUs (organizational units) in Google Workspace has become complicated, and we would like to understand which OUs are used for what and organize them by consolidating and eliminating unnecessary OUs. However, opening the configuration screens one by one from the management console takes a lot of man-hours, so we are considering whether we can use APIs to output the data in bulk, but we cannot find a good way. I would like to know if there are any tips on how to grasp the OU usage status with less man-hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free, open source GAM tool to print all of your OUs in list or tree form with their user and ChromeOS device counts: https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3/wiki/Organizational-Units#print-organizational-units

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Usage" are you referring to finding out what settings apply to each OU? Ie what services are turned on for each one and what setting's apply to each OU. Sadly the answer is NO . This is not possible though the API.

I came across this issue last year when we were auditing our environment. It took us many man hours to complete.  I submitted a feature request on the Google Cloud connect community. However , they migrated the Feature Request page from the Lumapps site cloudconnectcommunity.com to Googlecloudconnectcommunity.com However that feature request that I submitted was not transferred over.

You might want to submit a feature request or upvote ones that are relevant.

https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Feature-Ideas/provide-a-way-to-get-all-overridden-OU-settings/idi-p/169525

https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Feature-Ideas/Report-Organization-Unit-Settings/idi-p/81908